# JSoup error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I'm applying the following example http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links to list links.

```
package org.jsoup.examples;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Example program to list links from a URL.
 */
public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String url = args[0];
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
        Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

        print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
        for (Element src : media) {
            if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
                print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                        src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                        trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
            else
                print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
        }

        print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
        for (Element link : imports) {
            print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
        }

        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

I only replaced ""usage: supply url to fetch"" with "http://www.google.com". JSoup documentation is so poor (as I see). So, Im getting the following error & not able to figure out why: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: http://www.google.com
at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:16)

I found the following post about the same problem: [importing java libarary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709414/importing-java-libarary) But I already replaced usage: ... etc with the web site name and does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only replaced ""usage: supply url to fetch"" with "http://www.google.com".

Well that suggests you don't understand what the `Validate.isTrue` call is doing. It's incredibly important that you don't change code without knowing what it's doing before you change it.

You're not *meant* to change that code. You're meant to run this code and supply the URL as a command-line argument. That first statement validates that there *is* exactly one command-line argument.

So put the code back to what it is, and run

```
java -cp [whatever] org.jsoup.examples.ListLinks http://google.com
```

Comment: Is there any way I can run this code from eclipse not the command line ?? Because when I tried, it seems there is no way I can enter the link.

Comment: When I run the code from eclipse, I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: supply url to fetch
 at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
 at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:16)

Comment: @Mem: Yes - edit your run configuration to either prompt you for the command line arguments, or just hard code the command line arguments into the run configuration.

Comment: If you could explain how, I will b thankful. I'm not getting it yet. I'm trying to figure out which run configuration should I change http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html . But still confused.

Comment: @Mem: Change the run configuration that you're using to launch the program. See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-executionArgs.htm

Comment: Thanks. I could run it now after changing the run configuration. But what if I want the user to input the site to be extracted?

Comment: @Mem: Well will the user be running Eclipse? You can edit the run configuration to prompt the user if you need to - or if they're just running from the command line, they can provide the command-line arguments.

Comment: My goal is to make a web crawler that fetches domain names without repetitions? Now, I still don't know how to sanitize the fetched URLs to get the domain names only (e.g: google.com without http://www) & with no repetition. Do you advise me to continue with JSoup or do my crawler with reg. expressions? My problem with JSoup is that I'm not finding good resources as tutorials or so to start with. Plz advise I'm limited in time.

Comment: @Mem: I don't know how to advise you on that - I've never used JSoup myself (that I remember).

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of the preset from the website...I found this on another stack q&a

```
public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String url = "http://shopping.yahoo.com";
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
}
```

Comment: Please include the linky to the original Question from StackOverflow!